# How to extract two dimension input array from blade view in Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel

Hi I have 2 dimension input in blade view as below partial code.

```
.....
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>{{$provincialeducation->name}}<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
          <input type="number" name="projectallocation[{{$projectallocation->id}}][{{$provincialeducation->id}}]" value="{{old('projectallocation[]')}}" placeholder="" class="form-control" >
      </div> 
.....
```

In controller. I would like to try to extract request, but not luck..

```
  foreach( $request->projectallocation as $key1 => $item1 ){
      foreach( $request->projectallocation as $key2 => $item2 ){
          if(.....){
                .....
          }
       }
   }
```

Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Dump your variable and you will understand how to do it I guess

Comment: Dear Vincent Decaux, Thanks, Is this appropriate way?.

Comment: what's your input looks like?

Comment: Dear Andy Song, Input are created from two collections. eg category and book. Let's say, I have 5 cates and 3 books. So I can create 15 dynamic inputs in blade view. All input value will be passed to controller and extract them to DB.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solve problem. This code work for two dimension input.

```
foreach( $request->projectallocation as $key1 => $budget ){
    foreach( $budget as $key2 => $item ){
        echo 'category: ' . $key1 . ' budget: ' . $item . '<br />';
    }
}
```